# sha512 hash in python not equal to sha512 hash in php

Tags: php, python-3.x, encryption, hash

The sha512 hash using the `digest()` method is not equal to hash_hmac with sha512 in PHP.

Python:

```
print base64.b64encode(hmac.new("key".encode("ascii"),"hello".encode("ascii"), hashlib.sha512).digest())
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
  echo base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha512', "hello", "key")); 
?>
```

If I use `hexdigest()` method in python in place of `digest()` method, then the hash result is the same. I need to use the `digest()` method, so is there any equivalent method in php such that I can get same hash result?

Comment: did you compare them? where is the difference?

Comment: i replace digest() with hexdigest() method in python code, then i compared Python hash result with php hash result. both were equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that `digest()` in Python returns hash as a binary string, whereas `hash_hmac` in PHP returns hex-encoded string. So in PHP you'd do something like:

`echo base64_encode(hex2bin(hash_hmac('sha512', "hello", "key")));`

Comment: Thanks, i got same hash result.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please [mark my answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).